# iOS how to uiview know appear and disappear?

Tags: ios, uiview, subview

In view on viewcontroller i can know when view on screen by viewDidAppear.

But in subclassed view from UIView can't know.

In `android` each view has methods `didAttachToWindow` and `didDeattachFromWindow`

So i can know when view appear and disappear from screen.

Is exists something like in `iOS?`

Answer (score 17):

you can overwrite the following functions in your view to find out what happened to your view:

`removeFromSuperview` when removed and as already mentioned  `willMoveToSuperview:`/`didMoveToSuperview:` when added to a parent view.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Android (what attaching/deattaching means), but on iOS you can override the [willMoveToSuperview:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/willMoveToSuperview:) / [didMoveToSuperview:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/didMoveToSuperview) methods in your UIView subclass to receive a message in your UIView subclass. There's also [willMoveToWindow:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/willMoveToWindow:) / [didMoveToWindow:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/didMoveToWindow) methods in UIView that you can override that will let you know in the UIView when the view has been added to a Window.

Comment: This sends a notification when my view loaded. I want to get notified when my view removed from view. Any suggestions for that?